# Tree insertion with only a value

Tags: data-structures

How I make an insert method in java for a tree which only need a value i.e insert(int value)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be a tree.

In C++ for example, the tree would be a class, and then you would do `mytree.insert(5);`, which would insert 5 to an instance of a class that represents your data structure.

Comment: So you mean instead of giving an extra variable three to the method  .I could make the class a tree to avoid that?

Comment: An object oriented environment yes @IVnoobSuck. However, you didn't say much about the description of the data structure, so I am just guessing...